# Two of my wallet transfers have gone poof

Tags: transactions, wallet

To keep it tight, I was transferring seedify.fund from my CB wallet to crypto.com Cex and I hadn't seen it show up for a while. Transaction showed up on CB wallet but not my crypto.com defi wallet. And then in short succession same thing happened with a transfer of Slerf from solana to crypto.com wallet again.  I've looked at the block chain explorer as best I could but I'm honestly not that savvy with all the crypto behind the scenes. One thing I did notice was something called oncurve: true/false. One I saw was true and another false. Don't know what to make of it.  I had been trading willy nilly to get a feel for different defi wallets and then this happened. Anyone have a clue how to help, or atleast point why I'm an idiot?  Appreciate it thanks,

JR

Answer (score 1):

yo, oncurve just means that the thing you are calling is a PDA (program derived address) or not (of oncurve is true its not a PDA, if false it is).
you should verify that the crypto.com wallet you are using actually supports solana and that you are currently using the 'solana' mode (most of the wallets support several chains and you have to set the chain you want to use in the settings, by default they are often set to ethereum so maybe if you switch it to solana you'll see your funds).
else i'd recommend looking for help on the wallet specific discords, and make sure to double check who you'll be interacting with, those kind of discords are full of false support account trying to scam you.

best of luck

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I'll run thru and check on the things you mentioned. Tho to your point about making sure wallets accept a certain ecosystem- Do most wallets let you process a transfer/send to another wallet with an address that doesn't link up with the ecosystem you're trading? It could be false memories but I felt like I wasn't able to continue a couple of times bc I failed to realize I was sending Eth and was using Sol address or vice-versa. Thanks for your response and advice.  Also in forums like this or the ones you directed me to, would be wise (or dumb) to paste blockchain?

Comment: Responding to my comment I do remember seeing a ton of beware of sending to wrong addresses bc your crypto could just disappear to god knows where.. so if it's not something trivial that I'm missing I'm guessing I did that. Who knows. Thx again!

Comment: i believe most of the modern wallets dont allow you to send assets on another chain than the set chain but i havent used coinbase wallet nor crypto.com one so i cant say.

for the forums it really depends, this stackexchange is solana dedicated so its not necessary but if you get into broader ones id advise you to send as much details as possible (chain, transaction hash, wallet address) so persons reading through can get a full understanding.

Comment: Roger that, thanks again. Wish me luck. I have a feeling this might be one of those lessons learned the hard way.